# Writing pseudo code to print messages based on the content of variables a and b in the following table

Tags: python

Trying to write pseduo code to print messages based on the content of variables a and b as given in the following table. Anyones input is much appreciated.

```
    A               B            message          
more than 1    less than 5     message 1
1 or less      less than 7     message 2
more than 1    5 or more       message 3
```

Comment: If you want to write peudo code -- why did you tag `python`?  In any event, surely this is just a couple of simple `if` statements. What did you try?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply. I'm  new to the programming language and struggling a little bit. This is what i came up with so far.

               If a is more than 1  or less than 5 print message 1.
               If a is 1 or less than 7 print message 2.
               ?????

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the answer with Python, so I have provided a simple answer in Python.

This is straightforward using the Python [`if else` conditional statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html):

```
if a <= 1:
    if b < 7:
        print(message2)
else:
    if b < 5:
        print(message1)
    else:
        print(message3)
```